# Vue 2 - How to instantiate properly, at the right time

Tags: vue.js

One of the vue's instance of my app seems to instantiate too early. Even with a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`. As a consequence, I noticed that the event listeners aren't properly binded. A simple `@click="test"` (where test references to a `console.log`) didn't work.

Below, see the code where the `@click` doesn't work. It is a component located in a vue instance, instanciated on DOMContentReady :

```
const navBurger = {
    template: `
        <nav class="burgerNav"">
            <button class="burgerNav__icon" @click="test">
            </button>
        </nav>
    `,
    methods: {
        test: function() {
            console.log('test')
        }
    }
}

export default navBurger
```

I "solved" the problem by adding a little timeout (200ms) before instanciation to the root instance of this component but it seems a messy and fragile solution. Is there any clean way to instantiate at the exact right time ? I need this instance to be ready as quick as possible because it contains the navigation located in the header.

Below, find the loading order of the js files. Targetted file is `assets/js/components/nav/nav.js`. However changing this order doesn't solve the problem.

```
    <!--========== VUE ==========-->
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/libraries/vue.js"></script>

    <!--========== SCRIPTS ==========-->   
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/components/nav/nav.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/shop.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/script.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" defer></script>
```

Comment: Maybe add type and defer `<script src="<?= url('assets') ?>/js/libraries/vue.js" type="module" defer></script>`

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @Patfreeze It doesn't work. I think it would be difficult to reproduce since it seems to be related in particular to the loading order, thus dependent on all files.